# Javascript array of objects is acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function graphify( options ){
    var dataPts = [], temp = {};

    console.log("1 datapts", dataPts) //1 datapts []
    $.each(options.data, function(index, r){
        temp = {label: r.tag, y: r.value};
        console.log("temp", temp); //temp Object {label: "Tuscany", y: "1841990.0"}
        dataPts.push(temp);
        console.log("loop datapts", dataPts);//seen on the screenshot on the comments
    });

    console.log("2 datapts", dataPts)//same with the screenshot
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(options.wrapper, {
        title: { text: options.title },
        animationEnabled: true,
        data: [{
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: dataPts
        }]
    });
    console.log("3 datapts", dataPts)//same with the screenshot
    chart.render();
}
```

When I placed the data inside temp, it worked as I wanted but when I pushed the object into dataPts, it added an extra property, x="0", to the object. I don't want the x value in there because it messes up the plug-in. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w4a4j3do/ - just fine

Comment: Since there's no `x` property shown anywhere in the code you've included, this must not be the only code you have in your real code.  There must be something else going on in the real code.  Not much we can do since that code is not included here.  `.push()` does not magically add properties to the item it is pushing.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Because OP doesn't have reveled the `options`, nope nope nope can you add that in the question

Comment: @Tushar what ever its value is, we are reading only 2 values from that object `label` & `y`

Comment: http://imgur.com/fGYUFUV this is what I got in my app. Although, your jsfiddle is working fine.

Comment: @nopenopenope Don't just add screenshots, add complete code to work on

Comment: temp and dataPts are empty to begin with. Does options' value really matter?

Comment: there, added the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note here...

#### How `console.log()` really works

This line of code does not do exactly what you may expect:

```
console.log("loop datapts", dataPts);
```

That code does not log the *current value* of the `dataPts` array to the console. It only logs a *reference* to that array. So when you later expand `dataPts` in the console, you are not seeing its values from the time you called `console.log()`, you are seeing its values as they exist *when you expand it*.

So this does not necessarily mean that there was an `x` property in your array elements at the time of the `console.log()` call. The `x` could have been added later, at any time before you expand the array manually in the console.

If you want to log the actual values of an array or object as they exist when you call `console.log()`, a good way to do it is to use `JSON.stringify()`. This will convert the array to a string showing the values at the time of the call. You can use the optional `space` argument to have the output pretty-printed:

```
console.log( "loop datapts", JSON.stringify( dataPts, null, 4 ) );
```

#### Where did the `x` come from?

Since there is no `x` anywhere in your code, where is that `x` coming from? The CanvasJS code is adding it.

If you download the code from [the CanvasJS website](http://canvasjs.com/) and search the `canvasjs.js` file for `x` using a case-sensitive whole word search, you will run across this bit of code:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSeries.dataPoints.length; i++) {

    // Requird when no x values are provided 
    if (typeof dataSeries.dataPoints[i].x === "undefined") {
        dataSeries.dataPoints[i].x = i;
    }
    // ... more code here ...
}
```

See what's going on? It checks each element of `dataPoints` (which is your `dataPts` array) to see if it has an `x` property. If that property is not present, it adds the property right there.

I don't know the answer to your question of how to make the code work, but this is the explanation for the behavior you're seeing.

#### One other minor note

This code (taken from your question but with `console.log()` calls removed for clarity) should be changed just a bit:

```
var dataPts = [], temp = {};
$.each(options.data, function(index, r){
    temp = {label: r.tag, y: r.value};
    dataPts.push(temp);
});
```

`temp` should not be declared outside the `$.each()` like that. Instead it should be declared inside the `$.each()` callback, since that's the only place it is used:

```
var dataPts = [];
$.each(options.data, function(index, r){
    var temp = {label: r.tag, y: r.value};
    dataPts.push(temp);
});
```

Of course, at that point there's hardly a need for the `temp` variable at all. You could simply write:

```
var dataPts = [];
$.each(options.data, function(index, r){
    dataPts.push({ label: r.tag, y: r.value });
});
```

But there is an even simpler way to write this. Use `map` instead of `each`:

```
var dataPts = $.map( options.data, function( r ) {
    return({ label: r.tag, y: r.value });
});
```

Comment: My initial code didn't have temp but I added it so I can see the breakdown of the code and see where the x was added. Your post has been so informational. I'm gonna try $.map and see what happens.

About the plug-in adding the x variable, how come it works from these examples: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/

Comment: $.map produces the same thing. Maybe it was the plug-in that's adding it. I'm not sure how to fix this:

if I put:
data: [{
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: dataPts
        }]
it's gonna add x, but if i place:
data: [{
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [{ label: "banana", y: 18 },
         { label: "orange", y: 29 },
         { label: "apple", y: 40 },                                    
         { label: "mango", y: 34 },
         { label: "grape", y: 24 }]
        }]

it displays properly

Comment: I got it, it's the plug in that inserted the x. The problem was that it passed the string that's why the plug-in didn't work. I had to parseFloat.